# Google prediction api, Having the output as a list that have a variable size

Tags: machine-learning, predict, google-prediction

I want to train a model that will allow me to generat a **LIST** of tag related to certain text, my output list will have variable size depending in the context.  In the examples that i found, the model return always one output.
I am wondering if the Google prediction Api can help me and if there are any examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377290/unsupervised-automatic-tagging-algorithms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is what you will get when using a CATEGORICAL rather than a REGRESSION model. From the Google documentation: https://developers.google.com/prediction/docs/developer-guide#examples

*When you submit a query, the API tries to find the category that most closely describes your query. In the Hello World example, the query "mucho bueno" returns the result*

...Most likely: Spanish, Full results:

```
[
  {"label":"French","score":-46.33},
  {"label":"Spanish","score":-16.33},
  {"label":"English","score":-33.08}
]
```